# Get minor version of a document using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest

I have a requirement to get all minor versions of documents in document libraries and list items in lists within a specific SharePoint site(SPWeb). To simplyfy the solution, first I obtained all the items within a SharePoint site using the following REST Search API query.

```
https://mysharepointserver/sites/mysite/_api/search/postquery

Query Text : 'ContentClass:STS_ListItem'
```

So it returned all the items within my site. Now I need to get only the minor versions of this items. How should I update my query to get that information? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the minor versions? Do you need to get only specified minor version of the item / document or all minor versions of the item?

Comment: @ShanthaKumarThambidurai I need to get all the minor versions available for a specific item.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this

```
http://<serverURL>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/FolderA')/files(‘filename’)/minorversion
```

hope this can help you

Comment: If it helps you then mark it as answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer Milind. But this only returns the minor version number of a specific file. What I need is to get all the minor versions of items within a specific site.

Comment: You can loop all the files and get minor files

Answer (score 2):

At present, it seems impossible to obtain the version collection of a file or list item using Rest API.
This can be achievable through SPListItem.Versions from Server code or Lists.asmx web service from client side.
If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Could you please briefly explain how can we do that with Lists.asmx web service?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version on the SharePoint Online CSOM (16.1.4727.1200) allows the reading of older versions of documents:

https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365

I don't have an example to hand, just saying that the API does now support it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I need to use REST API to get these items.